# Does anyone know how to lighten a drawing from .tiff file?

Tags: scanner, editing, copy, tiff, drawing

I have a photocopy of an old machine drawing from 1982. It looks like it has been taped and I have been tasked with trying to edit the drawing so that it is eligible.  Other from lightening the saturation I haven't been very successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to accomplish at the end. Please clarify with visual examples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What software do you have access to? Photoshop, Gimp…?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "legible" instead of "eligible"?

Comment: Windows, Linux? Take a screen grab of a portion and show that in you posting. The actually used file format is really not telling much. Is the scan BW ("2 color"), Greyscale (e.g. 256 colors) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:

You might wish to play with the `Gimp-Menu:Color > Levels`

Locate the small triangles under the "Input levels" graph.
By moving these you can exclude left and right (black and white) nuances from the rendering of the image.
Then moving the middle triangle will place out "mid-grey" in the range between "black" and "white" as set by the other two.

[image]

This will allow some "cleaning" of a greyscale scan of e.g. an old technical drawing, or a text page. I'd say this is an "optimization" of the scan.

Example:
[https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/~yao/EL5123/SampleData.html](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/SampleData.html)
.. has an often used sample soft greyscale image of "Lena".

Using

```
106, 1.59  111
0           37
```

in the boxes, and then use `75  87` for Brightness-Contrast settings *(in the same menu)*

You can make the image look like this:
[image]

i.e. darker and with higher contrast.

Now that might not be the "correct thing" for your scan though; you might need it go lighter but still with higher contrast.

... similar effects can be created with "Curves" by dragging the ends of the straight line and then make it be an S-shaped curve, by placing out "nodes" on it.